# Trouble Integrating JavaScript into HTML with button onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have written and tested all my code in NetBeans and it works fine in the IDE.  When I try to integrate it into my webpage, my button onClick event does not execute.

I have this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://www.afanalytics.com/files/theme/2015.05.23_boilerUpgrade.js"></script>
```

I have uploaded the js file and verified that it exists in the webpage source code link.  However this button event does not call up the function like it does in NetBeans:

```
<input type="button" class="calcButton" value="Calculate" onClick="boilerUpgradeRun()">
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in jsfiddle?

Comment: Weird ... your `2015.05.23_boilerUpgrade.js` file you include contains `<script>` tags. Don't you have errors in your console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your external Javascript file has script tag . But external JS files expects only JS code without any script tag

So you need to remove

```
<script type="text/javascript"> at the beginning
```

from your http://www.afanalytics.com/files/theme/2015.05.23_boilerUpgrade.js file and also remove `</script>` from the end

Comment: That was it!  I should have known...I ran into this earlier.  I'm dumb :)  Thanks so much!